# Kinect Skeleton Offline Extraction

Tags: c++, kinect

what i am trying to do is this:
I have some images recorded with kinect and i only have the depth and color images.
Is there any way to extract skeleton data using that and the MS Kinect SKD?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have tried looking the documentation and searching the internet... :)

Answer (score 0):

Kinect SDK does not have that functionality. The only way to do that (in my opinion) is create your own algorithm or use OpenCV (EMGU for C#) or similar.

Check this link: http://myrandomtechnotes.blogspot.mx/2010_12_01_archive.html

P.S. Do you know the Kinect Studio?

Comment: That's what i was suspecting as well, but i thought to try asking anyway.... :)
I suppose i will try to impliment something on my own...
I know the Kinect studio, but i haven't used it yet....

Thank you!

Comment: I mentioned kinect studio because you can record kinect sessions and the playback to your kinect app.